# Circular Buffer in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, data-structures, stack, deque

I need a deque-like data structure, which I believe is called a circular buffer.

This is what I've done.

```
public class MyStack {


    byte[][] orders = {  {0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 1, 2}  };

    byte state      = 0;

    int[] data      = {1, 2, 3, 4};


    void swap(int value){           
        data[state] = value;

        if(state == 3){
            state = 0;

        }else{
            state ++;

        }       
    }

    int[] dump(){

        int[] output = {  
                          data[  orders[state][0]  ],
                          data[  orders[state][1]  ],
                          data[  orders[state][2]  ],
                          data[  orders[state][3]  ],
                       };

        return output;
    }

}
```

The output here is exactly the type of functionality I need. It is basically a window of length four, moving through a infinite, discrete space, or along a number line.

My question is: Is this solution efficient? Are there any built in libraries designed for this functionality? If so, is it worth using instead?

Comment: There is no `push` or `pop` operation - how is this an implementation of the stack ADT? If your data structure is not intended to work like a stack call it something else, or you will confuse people.

Comment: I'm not sure how a manual implementation of a stack would compare with built-in implementations (which are heavily reviewed). I do think the real question is what performance/usage issues did you run into? If implementing a stack isn't your goal - I believe it's not worth the overhead of not using the existing library.

Comment: @Joni The push and pop are both done at the same time in swap.

Comment: @Joni Okay, I see what you are saying. I suppose is isn't really a stack.

Comment: This is not a Stack. More a "least recently added integer buffer of fixed length". Frankly, for 4 integers, I really really doubt any implementation could be the performance bottleneck in an application. I don't find the implementation particularly elegant though: it's not really scalable due to the hardcoded orders array. You could just use the state to create a dump containing the end of the data array concatenated with its beginning.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, that's kinda true. I was thinking 'first in last out' and immediately assumed it was a stack. I'm going to edit the question. I thought about making things variable, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: In a stack push and pop both act on the "top" element. `swap` here seems to modify both ends of the list. Is this a queue (first-in-first-out) rather than a stack (first-in-last-out)?

Comment: @Joni Yes, push and pop occur simultaneously. It is also last-in-first out. The idea was to have something more like a 'window' that tracks the order of events with a length of four.

Comment: Going forward through time, that is.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, now that I think of it, I could have separated the push and pop, and this structure could be treated as a stack of fixed size.

Comment: are you sure it's not a ring a buffer that you want? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: @Joni Yeah, I think that's really what it is.

Comment: Okay I'm going to edit again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical implementation of a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) uses two indexes to mark the first and last element of the queue. There's no need to store the states explicitly because `enqueue` and `dequeue` can be done with index calculations. A better name for `swap` method is `rotate`.

You could remove the `orders` array and change the `dump` implementation to:

```
    int[] output = {  
                      data[  (state+0)%4  ],
                      data[  (state+1)%4  ],
                      data[  (state+2)%4  ],
                      data[  (state+3)%4  ],
                   };
```

Comment: I'm going to test this. But I wonder, do you think storing the states is faster than running four modulus calculations per iteration?

Comment: These functions may have as many as 10 or 20 running at the same time.

Comment: If performance is important to you, you should test it. Accessing an external array runs the danger of an expensive cache miss. Modulus of 4 can be optimized to a bitwise AND `&3`. My intuition is that the calculation is going to be faster than using an array.

Answer (score 2):

One improvement to this can be, remove the orders 2D array of size n.

```
byte[][] orders = {  {0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 1, 2}  };
```

because if you know the state , then the orders array can also be determined dynamically by formula

```
for(int i =0; i<data.length; i++){
  output[i] = data[(state+i)%data.length];
}
```

this can be used to return output.

Comment: Although it gives you a sense of improvement but I am more curious to know the situation in which you need this type of ADT, I appreciate if you can provide a little description of your problem requirement.